# Show that the set $\{I, (1\text{ } 2)(3\text{ } 4), (1\text{ } 3)(2\text{ } 4), (1\text{ } 4)(2\text{ } 3)\}$ of permutations is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that there are $4$ parts of showing this is true.

Suppose the name of the set is $A$.
1) Closure axiom. I need to show that $\forall$ $g, h$ $\in$ $A$, $g$ $\circ$ $h$ $\in$ $A$.
How do I show it ?

2) I think I have no problems with associative law. I just need to show that
$\forall$ $f,g,h \in$ $A$,  $f(gh)(x) = (fg)h(x)$.  This is $f(gh)(x) = f(g(h(x))) = (fg)h(x)$.

3) The identity map $I$ : $A \to A$ is identity element of $A$, because if $f$ is any permutation of $A$, then $I$ $\circ$ $f = f = f$ $\circ$ I. Have I proved it ?

4) Suppose $f$  $\in$ $A$. From the definition of permutation, $f$ is invertible and has an inverse $f$$^{-1}$. Therefore $f$ $\circ$ $f$$^{-1}$ $= I$. Have I proved it ?

Comment: You have a set of permutations acting on $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Just check (9 checks). Calculate what are the inverses - are they in your set (3 checks)?

Comment: You need to create a table and verify.

Comment: You don't need to check inverses since the set is contained in a finite group. It comes for free with closure. If you have closure, then $x^n$ eventually repeats from which you can find an inverse.

Comment: Associativity holds because the operation is composition of functions, which is associative.

Comment: Every one of these is its own inverse.

Comment: The $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ should be within MathJax, not outside of it. Thus: $$ \{I, (1\text{ } 2)(3\text{ } 4), (1\text{ } 3)(2\text{ } 4), (1\text{ } 4)(2\text{ } 3)\} $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(12)(34)=a$, $(13)(24)=b$ and $(14)(23)=c$.

Now, prove that $$ab=ba=c,$$ $$ac=ca=b,$$ $$bc=cb=a,$$ $$a^2=b^2=c^2=I$$ and check all axioms.

Can you end it now?

For example:
$$ab(1)=(12)(34)(13)(24)(1)=4,$$
$$ab(2)=(12)(34)(13)(24)(2)=3,$$
$$ab(3)=(12)(34)(13)(24)(3)=2$$ and
$$ab(4)=(12)(34)(13)(24)(4)=1,$$
which gives $$ab=(14)(23)=c.$$
Similarly we obtain the rest.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: Michael, I don't understand your logic. Could you please elaborate on this and explain it ?

Comment: @Rustem Sadykov I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Dihedral group $D_8$ (on the square with vertices $1,2,3,4$).

Then $f=(1 2)(3 4)$ is a flip around the line between the mid points of $1-2$ and $3-4$.
We have $f^2 = 1$

$r=(1 3) (2 4)$ is a rotation by $\pi$. We have $r^2 = 1$.

The $(1 4) (2 3)$ equals $f r = rf$ (and $(fr)^2 = 1$ from above).

Since $x^2 = 1$ for all elements we see that $x = x^{-1}$.